# Trying to store data in an 2d array in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, parse-platform

I have code that works but then I would have to add a new array and new code for every new country that my app will support and it is probably highly inefficient, as this code has to be run before the app starts and the view appears.

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)retrieveDictionaryOfCountryAndCompany {
    NSMutableDictionary *companyAndCountry = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *countryNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *germanyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *englandArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    PFQuery *companyQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: @"Company"];
    NSArray *objects = [companyQuery findObjects];
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        if ([[object valueForKey:@"country"]  isEqual: @"Germany"]) {
            [germanyArray addObject:[object valueForKey:@"name"]];
        }

        [countryNames addObject:[object valueForKey:@"country"]];
    }

    NSSet *uniqueItems = [NSSet setWithArray:germanyArray];
    germanyArray = [[uniqueItems allObjects] mutableCopy];
    uniqueItems = [NSSet setWithArray:countryNames];
    countryNames = [[uniqueItems allObjects] mutableCopy];
    [germanyArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    [countryNames sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    [companyAndCountry setObject:germanyArray forKey:@"Germany"];
    [companyAndCountry setObject:countryNames forKey:@"country"];
    return companyAndCountry;
}
```

Is there a better solution that I'm not seeing because it's too simple? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm being dense:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)retrieveDictionaryOfCountryAndCompany {
    NSMutableArray *countryNames = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableDictionary *companyAndCountry =
        [@{ @"country" : countryNames } mutableCopy];

    PFQuery *companyQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: @"Company"];
    NSArray *objects = [companyQuery findObjects];
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        NSString *countryName = [object valueForKey:@"country"];
        NSString *placeName = [object valueForKey:@"name"];

        if(!countryName || !placeName) continue; // a malformed record
        [countryNames addObject:countryName];

        NSMutableSet *namesInCountry = companyAndCountry[countryName];
        if(!namesInCountry)
        {
            namesInCountry = [NSMutableSet set];
            companyAndCountry[countryName] = namesInCountry;
        }

        [namesInCountry addObject:placeName];
    }

    for (NSString *key in [[companyAndCountry allKeys] copy])
    {
        NSArray *sortedArray = 
               [[companyAndCountry[key] allObjects] 
                   sortedArrayUsingSelector:
                        @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
        companyAndCountry[key] = sortedArray;
    }

    return companyAndCountry;
}
```

So just create and populate the lists on demand, initially as sets to avoid some of the array -> set -> array -> sorted array shuffle at the end.

As to performance, Parse is a web service so this should all be done asynchronously. Is that the case?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, it seems so easy now :D youre amazing thanks!